# steam engines and reciprocating engines

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I am going to make a couple of statements:
1)The four-stroke reciprocating engine has one power stroke in every two complete revolutions of the crankshaft. 
2)Two-stroke reciprocating engine has one power stroke in every full revolution of the crankshaft.
3)single-acting steam engine has one working stroke in each revolution.
4)double-acting steam engine has two working strokes in each revolution.

I have problem with the last two statements; actually, I am not getting how piston would return in the single-acting steam engine after completion of forwarding journey. And for the double-acting steam engine, we have two power strokes in each revolution!!! Wow! Then it must have more power than a four-stroke reciprocating engine. But we rarely see a double-acting steam engine in everyday use. Why is it so? Someone please help me out from this disorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a single-acting steam engine, the crankshaft is connected to a flywheel, which urges the crank to keep turning after the power stroke is finished. This returns the piston back to its starting position. Once the engine is running at normal speed, the flywheel arrangement keeps it going and all is OK.

Here is how a double-acting steam piston works.

the piston sits in the center of a cylinder. each end of the cylinder has a steam inlet in it. those steam inlets are connected to a valve that is operated by the crankshaft which feeds steam into one or the other end of the cylinder while also opening up the unfed cylinder to the air. the piston is connected to the crankshaft by a rod that emerges through one end of the cylinder through a tight seal. so, for example, steam enters the left end of the cylinder, pushing the piston to the right and letting spent steam escape from the right end of the cylinder. the crankshaft turns and the valve reverses itself, sending steam into the right end of the cylinder and venting the steam out of the left end. this was a very common arrangement in steam locomotives where lots of power was required in a compact space.